# SQL Query grab the most recent value that is NOT NULL, CURDATE()+2 no longer working

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have a MYSQL table called 'gas_market_prices' where I pull a column called 'dwgm_d2_provisional_price'. Now on a connected grafana dashboard I call this column, as I pull the most recent 'dwgm_d2_provisional_price' as shown in the attached image, which is always 2 days ahead of the current day.

[image: Database layout]

So previously, I was using the following query to get this recent price, where this query has suddenly stopped working even though the table is still being updated.

```
SELECT gas_date as 'time', dwgm_d2_provisional_price
from gas_market_prices 
where gas_date = curdate()+1
order by gas_date desc limit 1
```

How can I modify this script so that I get the 5.89 from dwgm_d2_provisional_price as depicted in the above image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query it appears that you need to add two days with current data instead of one.

```
SELECT gas_date as 'time', dwgm_d2_provisional_price
from gas_market_prices 
where gas_date = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
order by gas_date desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Best wishes.